# Running a python script in a virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x

How do I run a  python script in my virtual environment without source activate?

Is there a command like this?

```
python3 [virtual environment I use] Main.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your code with the python executable inside the virtual environment like this:

```
my_venv/bin/python3 my_script.py
```